# Writing to MemoryStream not working as expected

Tags: c#, stream, midi

I'm using the [DryWetMidi](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) library to process some MIDI data.

First I get the MIDI Data as a MemoryStream from the Clipboard:

```
MemoryStream ms = (MemoryStream)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData("Standard MIDI File");
MidiFile mid = MidiFile.Read(ms);
```

Then I do some stuff with the midi:

```
mid.RemoveNotes(n => n.NoteName == NoteName.FSharp);
```

Now I want to write it back to the Clipboard. I managed to do this like this:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.mid", FileMode.Create, FileAccess. 
{
   mid.Write(file);
}


using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.mid", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
     byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
     file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
     ms2.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);

     Clipboard.Clear();
     Clipboard.SetData(midiFormat, ms2);
}

File.Delete("file.mid");
```

As you can see, first I write the MIDI to a file, then I read that file into a MemoryStream which I then write into the Clipboard. This makes not much sense, because it would be simpler to write it to a MemoryStream directly. Also, I don't want to write a file to the users file system. But there's the problem. I tried it like this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
{
    mid.Write(ms2);
}
```

This doesn't give me an error, but the MemoryStream is completely empty. Calling ms2.Length results in a `System.ObjectDisposedException`.

How can I write the midi directly into the MemoryStream?

EDIT: Here's the link to the DryWetMidi [Write()](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/wiki/Writing-a-MIDI-file) Method.

Second Edit: Here's a piece of code that won't work:

```
MemoryStream ms = (MemoryStream)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(midiFormat);

MidiFile mid = MidiFile.Read(ms);
mid.RemoveNotes(n => n.NoteName == NoteName.FSharp);


MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
mid.Write(ms2);
var T = ms2.Length; //This will throw an exception
```

Third Edit: I am 100% sure that the code posted is exactly the same I'm running. Here's the [StackTrace](https://gist.github.com/Lucky2114/2d98946b2898f609d0da937dafcdd0db). (Gist because formatting was terrible on SO).

Comment: "*Calling ms2.Length results in a System.ObjectDisposedException.*" that will be because you called `ms2.Length` *after* the `using` block. The `using` block will dispose `ms2`. Make sure you use the MemoryStream *before* the end of your `using` block.

Comment: @canton7 It also happens when calling it inside the using block.

Comment: Then please post your actual code. You've posted a lot of code which "works", but none of the code which actually reproduces your problem

Comment: If you're passing the `MemoryStream` to `Clipboard.SetData`, then you shouldn't be disposing it (by putting it in a `using` statement). Otherwise, obviously, you're disposing a `MemoryStream` which is still in use. Instead, you will need to make sure that it's disposed when the Clipboard has finished with it, which is much tricker. Luckily, `MemoryStream` doesn't actually need to be disposed - it's just best practice - so you can get away with simply not disposing it. Alternatively, you can use the `byte[]` returned from `MemoryStream.ToArray`

Comment: Looking at your edit, no, that line will not throw. Either that code doesn't match the code you're actually running, or you've misinterpreted the exception you got. Please make sure that the code you posted matches the code you're running, and please also post the full exception and stack trace. We're getting to the point where we'll need a [mcve]

Comment: @canton7 Well yes, that is a good point. I edited my post and added a piece of code without disposing the MemoryStream and I still get the Exception.

Comment: @canton7 My guess is that, the library's .Write() Method somehow disposes the Stream. The same happens when using a FileStream, but there it's not problematic because I read the file from the hard-drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, DryWetMidi uses `BinaryWriter` to write to stream. And the default behaviour of `BinaryWriter` is that when it is disposed, It'll dispose the stream as well.

You can't read from MemoryStream when it's disposed but you can call `ToArray()`.

```
byte[] result;
using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
{
    mid.Write(ms2);
    result = ms2.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm the author of the DryWetMIDI. Thank you a lot for pointing out to the problem. DWM `Read`/`Write` methods mustn't affect passed streams. I will definitely fix the issue. `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` should be created with `leaveOpen` set to `true`.

Comment: Issue is fixed in the latest release.